How to make type inference work for a type parameter constrained by a union?
eg:
type AnyPtr[T any] interface {
    *T
}

type AnyPtrSlice[T any] interface {
    []*T
}

func FuncName[T AnyPtr[E] | AnyPtrSlice[E], E any](data T) (err error) {
}


type ModelAA struct {
    A int
    B int
}

func TestAddV2(t *testing.T) {
    var a = ModelAA{
        A: 1, B: 2,
    }
    _ = FuncName(&a)
}


This approach will be reported by the compiler as being unable to infer E. Is there any other way to write it?
I hope there is a way to solve it. I hope it won't be split into multiple methods.

Type inference does not work for cases where the constraint doesn't have a core type. That would likely require a polynomial time solver which isn't great for Go's promise of fast compilation time.
Union constraints such as *T | []*T, which is essentially the same as T AnyPtr[E] | AnyPtrSlice[E] don't have a core type. Emphasis mine:

An interface T has a core type if one of the following conditions is satisfied:

There is a single type U which is the underlying type of all types in the type set of T; or
the type set of T contains only channel types with identical element type E, and all directional channels have the same direction.

No other interfaces have a core type.

Note that when you write a union directly in the type parameter list FuncName[T AnyPtr[E] | AnyPtrSlice[E], E any] that is syntactic sugar. It's equivalent to writing:
type C[T any] interface {
   AnyPtr[T] | AnyPtrSlice[T]
}

func FuncName[E any, T C[E]](data T) error {}

You can see how the terms in the interface C are *T whose underlying type is itself, and []*T whose underlying type is itself.  But those underlying types are different, therefore C doesn't have a core type.
When type inference doesn't help, you have to instantiate the type arguments explicitly. If you move the type parameter E at the beginning of the list, that would be the only explicit required type argument, then T can be inferred from it.
// move E at the beginning of the type param list
func FuncName[E any, T AnyPtr[E] | AnyPtrSlice[E]](data T) error {
    return nil
}

func TestAddV2(t *testing.T) {
    a := ModelAA{}
    // supply a type argument for E
    _ = FuncName[ModelAA](&a)
}

